# Phoas in scala - Boxes go bananas for less

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

see https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/phoas

some background code

```
trait ProfunctorStr[->[_, _]] {
 def dimap[A, B, C, D]: (C => A) => (B => D) => (A -> B) => (C -> D) = { f =>
    g => {
      lazy val h: (A -> B) => (C -> B) = mapfst(f)
      lazy val hh: (C -> B) => (C -> D) = mapsnd(g)
      h andThen hh
   }
  }

  def mapfst[A, B, C]: (C => A) => (A -> B) => (C -> B) =
    f => p => dimap[A, B, C, B](f)(x => x)(p)

  def mapsnd[A, B, C]: (B => C) => (A -> B) => (A -> C) =
    f => p => dimap[A, B, A, C](x => x)(f)(p)

  // convenient for certain implementations
  def mfst[A, B, C](p: A -> B)(f: C => A): C -> B = mapfst(f)(p)

  def msnd[A, B, C](p: A -> B)(f: B => C): (A -> C) = mapsnd(f)(p)

 }


abstract class Rec[F[_, _], A, B] {
  def runRec[R]: (B => R) => (F[A, R] => R) => R
}

object Rec {
  abstract class RecProfunctor[F[_, _]](implicit F: ProfunctorStr[F]) 
    extends ProfunctorStr[({type l[x, y] = Rec[F, x, y] })#l] {
      def dimap[A, B, C, D] = { f =>
       g => rab =>
        def P = function1Profunctor
        new Rec[F, C, D] {
          def runRec[R] = { ??? }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

reading that article I feel like I get the gist but I'm having trouble implementing in scala, particularly how to transform that Rec[F, C, D] { runRec[R] = { ?!?!?! } } I really want to get this so if you can explain how to transform that

```
 (B => R) => (F[A, R] => R) => R
```

into

```
 (D => R) => (F[C, R] => R) => R
```

I think... 
Any way any and all help is very much appreciated, and detail as deeply loved. thank you

Comment: May be this could help: https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/profunctors

Comment: thanks @viorior I saw that. I'm not gonna say that I completely 'get' profunctors, but I read that.